# Plot many columns in a chart without unpivoting in Power Bi

Tags: powerbi, powerquery

First of all excuse me if it's obvious or I have missed something, but I tried to find a solution on the internet and in this forum and could not get a solution.

I have a dataset given to me by my company that it is as it follows:

[image: Example Table]

Basically it's a production log that is done in Excel. I am currently trying to develop a dashboard and have graphs that need the table in this way. However, when I try to plot a Column chart (normal, not stacked) one for each column with Data (I have close to 30 different Defect #) I get columns even for those columns that have all "null" values.

I browsed the internet and saw that the solution is to unpivot my table, and I have tried it without sucess because 1) It changed the data format that feeds my other graphs 2) I get errors that I do not know how where they come from.

Is there a way to plot the column chart without unpivoting the data? If not, Is there a way to feed one graph with the unpivoted data and the other with the "normal" one?

Thank you very much in advance!

Comment: Can you show your current problematic output of the chart. And also say what is your expectation.

Comment: You will need to unpivot but there is no need that this skrews other graphs. This you can do by in mquery create a new query  (blank) and give as start the name of other table. This is than the start data to unpivot

Answer (score 0):

I would create an additional table using unpivot, then you can use the appropriate table to suit any visual.

1. Open the Power Query Editor (Transform Data button on the Home
   ribbon)
2. Add an Index column to your existing query
3. Right-click your existing query and choose **Reference**.  This will create a new
   query that starts from the definition of your current query
4. Apply the unpivot in the new query and hit **Close & Apply**
5. Optionally, create a relationship between the original and unpivoted tables using the
   Index column. This will allow you to use slicers etc based on your original table.